# When to use the plural form (e.g. ‘pollutions’)

Tags: singular-vs-plural, british-english

There was a question in my test:

> People in big cities have to fight against different kinds of `pollution / pollutions`.

The reference answer was ‘***pollutions***’. My teacher said ‘*pollution*’ is a countable word.

I’ve looked up ‘*pollution*’ in different dictionaries, but all of them consider ‘*pollution*‘ a mass noun. I can’t find any articles of BBC that use ‘*different kinds of pollutions*’, they all use ‘*pollution*’.

Is this usage usual? Is it unnecessary to use ‘*different kinds of pollutions*’? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Pollution is normally uncountable, and the typical test answer would be to use the uncountable singular "pollution".

The countable form is possible but unusual.  It might mean "An incident of polluting" or "A pollutant".  In either of these senses the sentence would be better expressed differently.

So while "pollutions" doesn't break any grammar rules, it is not idiomatic and is a "wrong" answer for this question.

Answer (score 1):

"Pollution" is a non-countable noun, so you would not pluralise it. There are sometimes exceptions with non-countable nouns when they might be plural, but I cannot think of a single context where it could apply to pollution.

On the other hand, a *pollutant* is something that causes pollution, so these are countable. Likewise, there are many *sources of pollution*, so the word 'source' is pluralised.

The other thing to make sure of is that you correctly use 'kind' or 'kinds'.